# "Desde luego" meaning and etymology

Tags: modismos, etimología, adverbios

## Español

[Esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/789/understanding-desde-ya) me recuerda a una frase similar, "**desde luego**", que no es eso literalmente, sino que significa "por supuesto" ([según el DRAE](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=luego&val_aux=desde)):

> **luego.**
>   [...]
>   **desde ~.**
>
> 1. *loc. adv.* Ciertamente, indudablemente, sin duda alguna.
> 2. *loc. adv. p. us.* Inmediatamente, sin tardanza.

¿Alguien podría explicar cómo ha obtenido este signficado la frase?

---

## Inglés

[This question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/789/understanding-desde-ya) reminds me of a similar phrase, **desde luego**, which literally means "since later" but actually means "of course" ([according to RAE](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=luego&val_aux=desde)):

> **luego.**
>   [...]
>   **desde ~.**
>
> 1. *loc. adv.* Ciertamente, indudablemente, sin duda alguna.
> 2. *loc. adv. p. us.* Inmediatamente, sin tardanza.

Could anyone explain me how this phrase gained its current meaning?

Comment: +1 This one's definitely confused me too.

Comment: Here:http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=347048 they talk about "desde luego" the last entry is really interesting, but I'm in a hurry so if someone wants to elaborate an answer from it... please?

Comment: Do you mean "meaning *and* etymology"? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to parse the question title.

Comment: @hippietrail, the title was edited by someone else. Anyway I edited it as you suggested.

Comment: Oh, the wordreference discussion is great- short version: "desde luego" originally was used as "from now on" or "from then" in "law" stuff, and people interpreting it as "things should be *this* way" (i.e. "desde luego, todos los que roben pescado serán decapitados" -> "from now on, people who steal fish will be beheaded", then "desde luego" is associated with "this is the right way to do things").

Comment: Yo también uso DESDE LUEGO como una exclamación ante un hecho incorrecto o ante una injusticia, por ejemplo:
"-Hoy han vuelto a subir los impuestos.
- Desde luego... no sé dónde vamos a ir a parar."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He encontrado [este estudio](http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/15/15_0051.pdf) de María Antonia Martín, en el que se describe la *gramaticalización* de la frase ***desde luego***. Por gramaticalización se entiende un proceso histórico en el que una palabra deja de tener un significado referencial y pasa a tener solo una función gramatical.

Originalmente la expresión *desde luego* significaba lo que significa la unión de las palabras "desde" y "luego", esto es, *a partir de un momento muy próximo*, con función de complemento circunstancial de tiempo. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente fragmento del Quijote...

> Vine en fin donde el duque Ricardo estaba, fui dél tan bien recibido y tratado, que **desde luego** comenzó la envidia a hacer su oficio[...]

...la envidia no comenzó "por supuesto", sino ***inmediatamente***. Esta acepción está en la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=desde%20luego&m=form&o=h), como se indica en la respuesta de @pferor, y por supuesto ha dejado de usarse, aunque el documento de Martín recoge ejemplos de hasta 1932, y todavía está en el lenguaje judicial (puede verse en [este diccionario](http://www.ic-abogados.com/diccionario-juridico/res-nullius/22) jurídico online). Un uso similar se puede apreciar en el chilenismo *desde ya*, que significa *desde ahora mismo*.

Según Martín, "a través de un proceso de gramaticalización de índole pragmática (inferencial)" el uso original derivó al actual, en el que la frase ya no es un complemento que indica la circunstancia temporal del núcleo, sino una marca de modalidad que se adjunta a toda la proposición, y que puede ser reemplazado, como todos sabemos, por ***sin duda, ciertamente o evidentemente***. Incluso en algunos casos la frase es en sí una oración independiente:

> -¿Vas a venir?
>
> -Desde luego.

Con respecto a la gramaticalización inferencial hay abundante información en la internet. Como ejemplo puedo decir que es el proceso que subyace a la formación del tiempo futuro de tipo *voy a cantar* (el verbo "ir" dejó de significar "desplazarse de un lugar a otro") o la interjección *a ver* (que no significa "a" + "ver").

Answer (score 5):

«Desde luego» usually means *of course* in modern Spanish.

> **desde luego**.
>
> 1. loc. adv. Ciertamente, indudablemente, sin duda alguna. (*of course*, *certainly*, *without a doubt*)
> 2. loc. adv. p. us. Inmediatamente, sin tardanza. (*immediately*, *right now*, *without delay*)

The second definition is old Spanish (18th-19th century) and nowadays has only use in legal language such as in court. 
Later, this meaning was distorted and began to mean a confirmation of what was just said, and therefore the current meaning is that: *of course*.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you happen to have a source explaining the semantic shift you described?

Comment: @jrdioko Thanks.
No. I couldn't find any appropiate documentation for this subject. The only thing you can find is texts 200 years old with the old meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not have anything to do with the etymology of "desde luego".

One of the usages for the word "luego" is something like the English words "thus" or "therefore".  "Desde luego" may have been a phrase for "it follows logically" which may have morphed into "of course".

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that from the point of view of the future, one can look back on now and interpret "of course" into what happened as if it were predetermined.  Desde (from the vantage point of) luego (later on).....    .....as in it is easy to see how a thing came about once you know the rest of the story.  This is all my own supposition, but it makes as much sense

Comment: ¿Cómo aporta esta respuesta algo diferente a las otras?

Comment: The same way you tell the difference between a dog and a cat.

Comment: Funny, I had the same idea. But probably it's wrong...